# How can I make this jQuery faster than what I have?

Tags: jquery, performance, delay, fadein, fadeout

Currently, I am using this script for a type of "tab" system. When one tab is clicked, it hides all the others. They are all div's. But right now, I don't think it's fading fast enough before the selected div loads. It ends up getting shifted underneath the div that was selected and is now showing.

I don't want a toggle, because as you can see, I have 5 tabs that I want to open their respective "_s" div when they are clicked. Fade out, fade in.

Any way to make the fade out happen before the fade in, or maybe add in a delay? I do not know how to add in a delay into this script, or to check to make sure the div is completely faded before the new div fades in.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
<script>
$("#teach_one").click(function() {
    $("#teach_one_s").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#teach_two_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_three_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_four_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_five_s").fadeOut("fast");
});

$("#teach_two").click(function () {
    $("#teach_two_s").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#teach_one_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_three_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_four_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_five_s").fadeOut("fast");
});

$("#teach_three").click(function () {
    $("#teach_three_s").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#teach_one_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_two_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_four_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_five_s").fadeOut("fast");
});

$("#teach_four").click(function () {
    $("#teach_four_s").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#teach_one_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_two_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_three_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_five_s").fadeOut("fast");
});

$("#teach_five").click(function () {
    $("#teach_five_s").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#teach_one_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_two_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_three_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_four_s").fadeOut("fast");
});
</script>
```

Here's my HTML at your request:

```
<ul class="noselect teach_home_navigator_tabs">

<li id="teach_one">

</li>
<li id="teach_two">

</li>
<li id="teach_three">

</li>
<li id="teach_four">

</li>
<li id="teach_five">

</li>

</ul>


<div class="infotab teach_round" id="teach_one_s">  
stufff
</div>

<div class="infotab teach_round" id="teach_two_s">  
stufff
</div>

<div class="infotab teach_round" id="teach_three_s">    
stufff
</div>

<div class="infotab teach_round" id="teach_four_s"> 
stufff
</div>

<div class="infotab teach_round" id="teach_five_s"> 
stufff
</div>
```

Comment: If you post your mark-up, or a representative sample, we can probably simplify your jQuery. Quite a lot, I'd imagine.

Comment: if you showed your HTML this would be easier.

Comment: It wont let me add the HTML. it says i posted too many links.

Comment: check out my answer related to your markup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399632/how-can-i-make-this-jquery-faster-than-what-i-have/5399670#5399670

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your mark-up I can't be sure, but, and just to simplify your jQuery, and to reduce your repetition, you could try using something like this:

```
$('div[id^="teach_"]').click(
    function(){
        var showThis = this.id + '_s';
        $('#' + showThis).fadeOut('slow',
            function(){
                $('div[id$="_s"]').not($(this)).fadeIn('fast');
            });
    });
```

---

**Edited** in response to html provided by @Josh.

```
$('.each_home_navigator_tabs li').click(
    function(){
        var showThis = this.id + '_s';
        $('.infotab:visible').fadeOut('slow',
            function(){
                $('#' + showThis).fadeIn('fast');
            });
    });
```

References:

- [attribute-starts-with selector: `^=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [attribute-ends-with selector: `$=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Comment: Why fadeOut is the callback of fadeIn?, I think it should be the other way around

Comment: yeah, he's right... if I could see the HTML I'm guessing this is even more simple than this

Comment: @Eric, yeah, that'd be my preference too, but looking at the way he's set up his fx queue it appears he *wants* to `fadeIn()` before `fadeOut()`. Though this confuses me, somewhat.

Comment: And there's really no reason to fade out all of the other content, since there SHOULD only be one currently displayed at any given time. I hate this guy... j/k, I love him

Comment: @hunter, I make *one* simple *suggestion* on *your* answer and... =D yeah, you're right, but look at his jQuery. I mean: **ugh**. I'm just covering the bases and trying to make sure, really...but who knows what else is happening under there? =b

Comment: we came up with same solution, really, but there's no way to know. We're just sitting, waiting, and hoping that Josh shows us some GD markup

Comment: @hunter, yep, pretty much. Well, honestly, I'm off to bed, now (yay for UK time...) but I'll get up and see if there's been an update in by morning. Just on the off-chance... =)

Comment: @Eric, my answer edited after re-reading the question and seeing the 'Fade out, fade in' bit. Should've seen it the first time, really... =/

Comment: Add the href into your question in the form of `www.domain.com` or `www dot domain dot com` and someone with sufficient rep will edit it in for you.

Comment: This will work assuming not other unrelated id's on the site that ends with _s or begins with teach. ex: like whatever_s or teach_whatever

Comment: @Josh, I edited into the question about three minutes ago (as of this writing)... =)

Comment: @Josh, you're welcome! Have you checked to see if any of the posted answers help resolve your problem?

Comment: @Josh, have you had opportunity to test any of the posted jQuery scripts? Has your problem been solved? If the problem is *not* solved, please edit your question to include a description of the new problems, or the 'what happened.' Otherwise, if the problem **is** solved, please accept and/or up-vote any answer(s) that proved useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Updated based on your HTML

```
<ul class="noselect teach_home_navigator_tabs">
    <li id="teach_one">one</li>
    <li id="teach_two">two</li>
    <li id="teach_three">three</li>
    <li id="teach_four">four</li>
    <li id="teach_five">five</li>
</ul>

<div class="infotab teach_round" id="teach_one_s">stufff</div>
<div class="infotab teach_round" id="teach_two_s">stufff</div>
<div class="infotab teach_round" id="teach_three_s">stufff</div>
<div class="infotab teach_round" id="teach_four_s">stufff</div>
<div class="infotab teach_round" id="teach_five_s">stufff</div>
```

and you can easily wire up some functionality like so:

```
$(function(){
    $(".infotab").hide(); // hide all content on load
    $("#teach_home_navigator_tabs li").click(function(e){
        var id = this.id;
        var $current = $("#infotab:visible"); // get the currently selected tab
        if ($current.length == 0) { }           
            $(current.fadeOut("fast", function() { // fade out current
                $("#" + id = "_s").fadeIn("slow"); // fade in selected
            });
        }
        else { $("#" + id = "_s").fadeIn("slow"); } // fade in selected if no current
    });

    $(".teach_home_navigator_tabs li:first").click(); // click first tab on load
});
```

Comment: `this.id` is, by all accounts, a *little* faster, and achieves the same result. :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to make you feel silly, but it's one of those mistakes I remember making a *lot* when I first started with jQuery...just trying to help =)

Comment: just whipped something up, but yeah, I rarely need the id because I don't write markup that would require such hackeries.

Comment: +1 for the quick whippery, and the usual avoidance of hackeries =)

Comment: Hey guys, i cannot add my HTML. Here it is:

Comment: Was that html provided. Are you making your own??

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write your code like this. All #id's `fadeOut` except for the one clicked, it `faddIn`

```
$("#teach_one, #teach_two, #teach_three, #teach_four, #teach_five").click(function() {   
    var idd = this.id;
    $("#teach_one_s, #teach_two_s, #teach_three_s, #teach_four_s, #teach_five_s").fadeOut("fast ");
    $("#"+idd+"_s ").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: comparing this with david's, this seems to perform faster, http://jsperf.com/teach

Comment: @Haochi, i don't think you understand how jsperf works. The higher the number the faster. Your code is 32% slower.

Comment: Hmm, [not in Chrome](http://i.imgur.com/bUo1A.png)! Although I will take what I said. :)

Comment: @Haochi, i agree in Chrome your's is 16% faster, But in both IE and Firefox mine is 38%-45% faster then both yours and Davids :-). I did like the way you approached the solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
$("#teach_one").click(function() {
    $("#teach_one_s").fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $("#teach_two_s").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#teach_three_s").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#teach_four_s").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#teach_five_s").fadeOut("fast");
    });
});
```

Repeat for the rest, basically this waits for fadeIn to finish then calls the callback function to fadeOut the rest.

But your code can be significantly shorter IMHO, if you show your html I bet it can be compressed into one `click` binding.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$('#teach_four_s').animate({opacity:0},200)
```

where 200 is milliseconds for effect duration

This will allow you to have better control over the timing of the transitions

Comment: numbers work in place of the 'fast'/'slow' business too....no reason to use `.animate` really.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my HTML that I am using.

```
<ul class="noselect teach_home_navigator_tabs">
```

stufff


  
stufff


    
stufff


 
stufff


 
stufff