# JQuery Still Not working.. Slow and too quick at the same time

Tags: jquery, performance, html, jquery-effects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make this jQuery faster than what I have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399632/how-can-i-make-this-jquery-faster-than-what-i-have)

Currently, I am using this script for a type of "tab" system. When one tab is clicked, it hides all the others. They are all div's. But right now, I don't think it's fading fast enough before the selected div loads. It ends up getting shifted underneath the div that was selected and is now showing.

I don't want a toggle, because as you can see, I have 5 tabs that I want to open their respective "_s" div when they are clicked. Fade out, fade in.

Any way to make the fade out happen before the fade in, or maybe add in a delay? I do not know how to add in a delay into this script, or to check to make sure the div is completely faded before the new div fades in.

I posted this same question a few days ago but haven't found an answer thats correct yet.

Here's my current working script to shuffle the tabs. Stack is formatting it weird. Edit the post and read if you need.

Before anything happens, I made a separate script to hide all the div's on load except the first tab. Can this be integrated into your solution so I don't have a hundred scripts? Here's the source:

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#campus_infotab_two_s,#campus_infotab_three_s,#campus_infotab_four_s,#campus_infotab_five_s').hide();
});
  </script>

Now here's the script that controls the "tabs."

    <script>
$("#teach_one").click(function() {
    $("#teach_one_s").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#teach_two_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_three_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_four_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_five_s").fadeOut("fast");
});

$("#teach_two").click(function () {
    $("#teach_two_s").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#teach_one_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_three_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_four_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_five_s").fadeOut("fast");
});

$("#teach_three").click(function () {
    $("#teach_three_s").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#teach_one_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_two_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_four_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_five_s").fadeOut("fast");
});

$("#teach_four").click(function () {
    $("#teach_four_s").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#teach_one_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_two_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_three_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_five_s").fadeOut("fast");
});

$("#teach_five").click(function () {
    $("#teach_five_s").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#teach_one_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_two_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_three_s").fadeOut("fast");
    $("#teach_four_s").fadeOut("fast");
});
</script>
```

Now, here's the HTML that it makes pretty:

```
<ul class="noselect teach_home_navigator_tabs">
```

stufff


  
stufff


    
stufff


 
stufff


 
stufff

Here's some suggestions I have had, but none work. The one provided by hunter seems like it should work, but it says there is a syntax error somewhere and I'm not that good with jquery to diagnose. Thank you!

[How can I make this jQuery faster than what I have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399632/how-can-i-make-this-jquery-faster-than-what-i-have)

Answer (score 0):

This is hunters code fixed to remove his errors. I used http://www.jslint.com to find the problems.

```
$(function(){
    $(".infotab").hide(); // hide all content on load

    $("#teach_home_navigator_tabs li").click(function(e){
        var id = this.id;
        var $current = $("#infotab:visible"); // get the currently selected tab
        if ($current.length === 0) {           
            $current.fadeOut("fast", function() { // fade out current
                $("#" + id + "_s").fadeIn("slow"); // fade in selected
            });
        }
        else { $("#" + id + "_s").fadeIn("slow"); } // fade in selected if no current
    });

    $(".teach_home_navigator_tabs li:first").click(); // click first tab on load
});
```

Try it, but you probably shouldn't have asked another question for the exact same thing as you already had a question with a lot of responses. You should leave comments / edits on your old question in order obtain an answer.